# Job need to run on the 4th working day and 6th working day in autosys

Tags: autosys

I have Job A that need by schedule to run on the 4th working day and 6th working day .
I created two extended calendars for 4th and 6th working day using the keywords WORKD#4 and WORKD#6 in the Date Conditions.

however I am not able to attached to extended calendars to one job  .

could you please help me in this scenario how to run a job every month on the 4th and 6th working

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create only one extended calendar with Date Conditions "WORKD#4 or WORKD#6"

Comment: this work for me , so I think I can use and or in the conditions